# Twitterで重複しないデータを取得する方法

Tags: python, twitter

以下のコードでTweetからデータを取得すると、同じIDのTweetを取得してしまいます。
同じIDのTweetを取得しないようにするためには、どのようにコードを変えれば良いか
ご教示頂けないでしょうか。

```python
def auth():
    return os.getenv('TOKEN')

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers

def create_url(keyword, max_results = 100):
    search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent" 
    query_params = {'query': keyword,
                    'max_results': max_results,
                    'expansions': 'author_id,in_reply_to_user_id,geo.place_id',
                    'tweet.fields': 'id,text,author_id,in_reply_to_user_id,geo,conversation_id,created_at,lang,public_metrics,referenced_tweets,reply_settings,source',
                    'user.fields': 'id,name,username,created_at,description,public_metrics,verified',
                    'place.fields': 'full_name,id,country,country_code,geo,name,place_type',
                    'next_token': {}}
    return (search_url, query_params)


def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params, next_token = None):
    params['next_token'] = next_token  
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers = headers, params = params)
    print("Endpoint Response Code: " + str(response.status_code))
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()

#Inputs for the request
bearer_token = auth()
headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
keyword = '"global leader" -is:retweets -is:replies -is:links lang:en'
max_results=100

url = create_url(keyword, max_results)
json_response = connect_to_endpoint(url[0], headers, url[1])
```